Why cookies can not be returned?
I have the following firefox extension. I want to get cookies from the browser. But when I click "All" in the extension, the console.log(await (browser.cookies.getAll({})) only print an array of zero length. I tried to compare with the following package, but I can not see what is the difference that causes the problem. How can I find out what causes the problem?
https://github.com/hrdl-github/cookies-txt
manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "DefaultPopup",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "downloads"
    , "cookies"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup/choose_option.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["runtime.js"]
    }
  ]
}

background.js
browser.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
  console.log('onInstalled');
  console.log(details);
});

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async function(details) {
  console.log('onMessage');
  console.log(details);
  console.log(
    await (browser.cookies.getAll({}))
  );
});

runtime.js
console.log(browser)
/*
console.log(browser.downloads)
console.log(browser.runtime)
console.log(browser.runtime.id)
*/

popup/choose_option.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button class="all">All </button>
    <script src="choose_option.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

popup/choose_option.js
document.querySelector(".all").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log('click')
  browser.runtime.sendMessage("my message");
  window.close();
});


Consider use Manifest v3 instead. Here says v2 is outdated-

Manifest v2 is not outdated, but that's a political issue, not a technical one for Firefox.

I'm not sure if you're still having problems, but the extension needs permission to the tabs or the URLs whose cookies you want to get. tabs to allow getting the cookies (in the default store) from open tabs. *://*/* or <all_urls> to allow getting all cookies (in the default store), even for origins that are not in open tabs.
...
  "permissions": [
    "downloads",
    "cookies",
    "*://*/*"
  ],
...

Since I mentioned it above, the optional storeId property of the details parameter is

firefox-default (or nothing) for cookies in normal windows (with no identity)
firefox-private for cookies in private windows
firefox-container-N, where N is a number, for contextual identities

You can only get one store at a time.
